# setup rust + gtk::Application to ignore --config argument

Tags: rust, gtk, gtk3

I am displaying a UI in a rust based application using gtk3. I am parsing the arguments in the main method for a `--config` argument in order to find a custom configuration file. The gtk::Application object also does some command line processing and is complaining of

```
Unknown option --config
```

How do I prevent gtk from processing the command line or exclude config from gtk command line processing?

Comment: Same question here. It's an annoyance for Rust applications because it's customary to use `clap` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

gtk::Application has both a `run` and `run_with_args` command ([src](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk-rs-core/stable/0.14/docs/gio/prelude/trait.ApplicationExtManual.html#tymethod.run_with_args)). If you pass an empty array into `run_with_args` then gtk won't have any arguments to complain about and you can parse them yourself however you like.